# Why is the gravitational multipole expansion taken with the origin at the centre of mass instead of the centre of gravity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, multipole-expansion

Wikipedia's [article on the multipole expansion of the gravitational potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential#Multipole_expansion) expands it as
$$
 V(\mathbf{x}) = - \frac{GM}{|\mathbf{x}|} - \frac{G}{|\mathbf{x}|} \int \left(\frac{r}{|\mathbf{x}|}\right)^2 \frac {3 \cos^2 \theta - 1}{2} dm(\mathbf{r}) + \cdots
$$
with respect to a system of reference with the origin at the centre of mass $\mathbf r_\mathrm{COM}=\int\mathbf r\: \mathrm dm(\mathbf{r})$ of the mass distribution.

I don't understand this choice of system of reference. Why is the origin taken at the centre of mass? To me it seems to make more sense to put the origin at the [centre of gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass#Center_of_gravity), where the gravitational potential is 0. In the center of mass, it may not be!

Comment: Please don't ask us volunteers to click all over the web.  Make your questions self-contained.  Few people will bother with the question.  And the links might disappear over time.

Comment: You would rather I spend few hours writing formulas here which I don't know how to format! People knowledgeable of the subject don't need to click on those links.

Comment: @Ruslan That's not quite correct, particularly with the definition linked to by the OP.

Comment: The question is not particularly clear. Gravitational potentials are not, by themselves defined "in relation to" any particular point, though some approximations do have a specific centre. If you mean 'why is the multipole expansion taken with respect to the centre of mass?' then the answer is that it doesn't have to, though it is often convenient to do so. If that is your question, edit your post to make that clear.

Comment: As I often tell my students, "I don't understand" is not a question, at least not on its own.

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty: edited question per your suggestion.

Comment: @Michael Seifert: I am glad I am not your student :P

Comment: @anonymous Take Michael's advice on board. Saying "I'm confused" without saying what you're confused about does nothing at all to help the person who's meant to explain what it its they actually need to explain.

Comment: question was in the title itself! I edited further my confusion! :)

Comment: Do you think that alienating the people who are trying to help you will result in a better answer?

Comment: No. Alienating people who post question does not help either!

Comment: @anonymous I have edited both your questions for clarity and to make them self-contained. Please study the differences and take them in consideration in your future questions. You're not required to post at this standard, but you should note the clarity that you should be shooting for. You said earlier you don't know how to write maths using LaTeX - now is the time to learn! See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/) for a tutorial. (In this particular case the source is taken directly from wikipedia.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The multipole expansion in its most general form reads
$$
V(\mathbf r)=\sum_{l=0}^\infty \sum_{m=-l}^lQ_{lm}\frac{Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi)}{r^{l+1}},
$$
where the $Q_{lm}$ are the multipole moments of the system and the $Y_{lm}$ are spherical harmonics, and in this form it is applicable to bodies of any shape, and located at any point in space, so long as the body is contained in a finite spherical region of radius $R$ and the test point $\mathbf r$ is located outside this spherical region.

The [Wikipedia article you linked to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_potential#Multipole_expansion) is concerned with the first few terms in this expansion, which can be rewritten as

$$
V(\mathbf r)=-\frac{GM}{r}+\frac{\mathbf d\cdot\mathbf r}{r^3}+\frac{p_2(x,y,z)}{r^5},
$$
where $p_2$ is a traceless homogeneous quadratic polynomial, and the dipole moment of the system is defined as
$$
\mathbf d=G\int\mathbf r\:\mathrm dm(\mathbf r). \tag 1
$$

These first three terms go down with the distance to the origin $r$ as $1/r$, $1/r^2$ and $1/r^3$ respectively, which means that the *relative* importance of the second, dipole term goes as $1/r$ with respect to the first, monopole term.

This changes, however, if you set up your origin at the centre of mass of the distribution, since then the dipole moment $(1)$ vanishes. If you do this, then you can completely ignore the dipole term, and the subleading term of the expansion becomes the quadrupole term, which goes as $1/r^2$ of the monopole term, which makes the truncated series much more accurate.

That's about it, really.

---

In addition, though, you should note that the centre of gravity as you've linked to cannot be defined for a body in isolation: it is a property of a mass distribution $\mathrm dm(\mathbf r)$ *and* an externally-produced gravitational field $\mathbf g(\mathbf r)$ acting on the distribution. In these conditions you can find the total force
$$
\mathbf F=\int\mathbf g(\mathbf r)\mathrm dm(\mathbf r)
$$
and the total torque with respect to an arbitrary origin $\mathbf r_0$,
$$
\boldsymbol\tau=\int(\mathbf r-\mathbf r_0)\times\mathbf g(\mathbf r)\mathrm dm(\mathbf r),
$$
and then you can define the centre of gravity as the $\mathbf r_0$ at which $\boldsymbol \tau$ vanishes. If you don't have the external field $\mathbf g(\mathbf r)$, though, this doesn't make any sense: the centre of gravity is the point through which a given field configuration can be thought of as acting, and it depends on the field configuration.

Comment: Comment about 'centre of gravity' which is a comment to all three answers: Does not Earth, as non-homogeneous body, have a center of self gravity? I am probably missing something fundamentally simple here.. :(

Comment: The "centre of self-gravity" of any mass distribution must always coincide with its centre of mass, or otherwise the mass would exert a torque on itself and start spinning on its own. Similarly, the total self gravitational force must vanish, or the mass would spontaneously accelerate. The second example is implemented in practice by Newton's third law pairwise on all the particles; the vanishing torque is due to the anti-symmetry of the torques exerted within each pair.

Comment: But aren't all bodies in the Universe spinning? Maybe not on their own, but maybe also due to this difference in centers?

Comment: Also, this difference may be too small to detect the tiny spinning that may exist?

Comment: No. There's a difference between having a constant spin (which is fine) and a constantly accelerating spin, which breaks the sinceramente of energy. The constant torque I mentioned would do the latter.

Comment: Oh. Sinceramente -> conservation. Blame mobile keyboards.

Comment: I went through the whole thing again and realized I don't understand it after all. Why would there be a torque if the situation can be approximated with a dipole of two different point masses connected with the rigid rod?

Comment: You don't understand what? There's a huge number of concepts flying around, and saying you're confused without saying which one is the problem is not at all helpful. If this is about your 'centre of self gravity', it's probably best if you ask it separately.

Comment: @anonymous Upon further calculation, my initial comment on the centre of self gravity of a rigid body is not quite correct, because as it turns out the self-torque will *always* vanish, again because of conservation of angular momentum. More practically, if you calculate $\boldsymbol \tau$ as I've defined it for $$\mathbf g(\mathbf r)=G\int\frac{\mathbf r-\mathbf r'}{\|\mathbf r-\mathbf r'\|^3}\mathrm dm(\mathbf r')$$ then $\boldsymbol\tau\equiv0$ independently of $\mathbf r_0$. There is then no way to define the CSG - there's no unique $\mathbf r_0$ for which the torque vanishes.

Comment: You should do this calculation yourself, but it boils down to expressing $\boldsymbol\tau$ as an antisymmetric function of $\mathbf r$ and $\mathbf r'$, $$\boldsymbol\tau=\iint\mathbf t(\mathbf r,\mathbf r') \:\mathrm dm(\mathbf r')\mathrm dm(\mathbf r),\quad \mathbf t(\mathbf r,\mathbf r') =-\mathbf t(\mathbf r',\mathbf r), $$ integrated symmetrically so that it must vanish.

Comment: First, thank you Emilio and others for your promptness, time, and answers. Second, guys, I need to make one comment about this site. The dynamics of these questions/answers is a bit intimidating. I got several scoldings for asking my questions. Why my questions are not clear enough, why this or that.. If I knew better how to ask them, maybe I would find answers myself! Also, this thing about separating very connected questions into new ones seems like a chase for points and reputation thing, more than really them being unrelated. Just first impression after my 'initiation' in this community.

Comment: @anonymous We understand - believe it or not, we were all intimidated newcomers at some point - but take it from me that all these things have their reasons. Your questions are somewhat connected but they're not really that close; instead, all that this makes is a confusing thread of mixed comments about different questions which makes it very hard for future visitors to make sense of what's happening. We want them to see a well-asked, self-contained question first thing, and a full answer straight up - not have to navigate a maze of comments to puzzle things out.

Comment: Having the questions separate is in no way a chase for points - it's a way to make this site useful for future visitors, who are the real audience of this site and the primary reasons we write answers. Similarly, if we tell you that your question isn't clear enough, it's because it's either hard or impossible to answer, and it's to help you make it answerable and ultimately to help you get the answers you're looking for. Asking good questions does take time and skill but it's the least you can do when you're asking others to volunteer their time to help you.

Comment: I should also apologize on behalf of some site members who did this in maybe a rougher tone that was strictly necessary. However, you should realize that you do need to mirror the effort you want others to put into your answers with the effort you spend crafting your questions, and at the very least you need to be receptive when your prospective answerers tell you there's problems with your question that make it unanswerable. Take it easy, though - it will get better with time and practice.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike the centre of masss the centre of gravity is not an intrinsic property of a mass distribution. The centre of gravity only becomes distinct from the centre of mass when there is an external gravitational field that is non-uniform i.e. varies significantly across the distribution of masses. If the external gravitational field is higher on one side of the mass distribution than the other it effectively pulls the centre of mass towards the higher gravity side.

The multipole calculation you describe involves no external gravitational field so the centre of gravity coincides with the centre of mass.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are puzzled because you are not distinguishing the gravitational potential produced by the system and the one acting on the system.

The multipole expansion you link to, is performed on the expression for the potential produced by the system on a distant point. In this case the system has a mass center, but no gravity center can be defined for it without having an external gravitational field acting on it. Also the resulting field will be always along the line passing by the center of mass, that is why is convenient here.

But when you have an external gravitational field acting over some system, you can define a gravity center for it, as the point which would not "feel" any torque regardless of the system orientation in the external field, or just using the formula you linked to. But in this case it might not coincide with the mass center because the field might be inhomogenous throughout the system, so different parts can feel different forces.

Summing up, the choice is based on the symmetry of the potential (the field produced by the system always points towards its mass center) and because no gravity center can be defined w/o external field.

Comment: i agree that's the main point of confusion. see my comment on the accepted answer.